# amplitude frequency response in mathematica

Tags: nonlinear, frequency

I am solving the Rayleigh-Plesset equation, which includes the forcing. I want to plot a frequency-amplitude relation numerically in Mathematica, but I am unable to do it. I am providing the Non-dimensional form of the Rayleigh-Plesset equation. Any help would be appreciated to write a code to plot the same.
`RR''+(3/2)R'^2=(1+We)R^(-3k)-1-(We/R)-(4Re*R'/R)+F*Sin(wt)`
where `R` is a function of `t` and `'` represent the derivative with respect to `t`, `We` and `Re` are the non-dimensional numbers, `w` is the forcing frequency, and `F` is the forcing. Thanks

Comment: Can you give what the values of the parameters `F,We,Re,k,w`?  You want to plot the frequency of `F` against its amplitude?

Comment: `F=2`, `We=0.145`, `Re=10`, `k=1.4`.  Actually, this is an oscillation problem, so I want to plot the frequency `(w)` against the oscillation amplitude.

Comment: What are the initial conditions?

Answer (score 2):

May be

[image]

Change as needed:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
F=2;We=145/1000;re=10;k=14/10;
ode=R[t]*R''[t]+(3/2)*R'[t]^2==(1+We)*R[t]^(-3*k)-1-(We/R[t])-(4*re*R'[t]/R[t])+F*Sin[w*t]
ic={R[0]==1,R'[0]==0};
sol=ParametricNDSolve[{ode,ic},R,{t,0,100},{w}]
Manipulate[Module[{sol1},
   sol1=R[w]/.sol;
   Plot[sol1[t],{t,0,100},PlotRange->{Automatic,{.8,1.5}},
    PlotStyle->Red,GridLines->Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle->LightGray,AxesLabel->{"time","F(t)"},BaseStyle->12]
],
{{w,0,"w"},0,2,.1,Appearance->"Labeled"},
TrackedSymbols:>{w}
]
```